# How can I display on laravel blade name instead of id?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

User can create invitations, and I want to display the user name who sended the invitation and the email who got it but not working

Invite.php

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

User.php

```
public function invites()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Invite::class);
}
```

InvitationController.php

```
public function index()
{
    $invites = Invite::all();
    return view('administrar', compact('invites'));
}
```

administrar.blade.php

```
   <select class="form-control input-lg">
          @foreach ($invites as $invite)
            <option>{{$invite->email}} invitado por {{$invite->user->name}}</option>
          @endforeach
     </select>
```

Comment: Do u have user attached to that invite?

Comment: what do you mean? invite table its just a code, email, and user id who has sended the invitation

Comment: ```$invite->user``` what that gives you?

Comment: nothing :( just empty, $invite->useID give me the user id who send the invitation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HasMany` expects `user_id` to be a foreign key. (Snake case)

In your case, it's something different you need to tell the relationship what to `foreign key` you have.

So your relation should be like this,

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'useID');
}
```

Or rename the `foreign key`.

Check the documentation for more details

[Eloquent: One to Many.](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

Comment: thanks it's working perfectly i had alredy changed the user class with return $this->hasMany(Invite::class, 'useId'); didn't know i had to change this on Invite class too!